# Do I have to rebind my PDO parameters when I reuse the (slightly modified) query?

Tags: php, pdo

Before I insert a row, I want to check for its existence, in order to avoid duplicates.

So, I

```
$pdo = ConenctToDatabase();

// Check for existence - don't add a duplicate
$sqlQuery = $pdo->prepare('SELECT campaign_id FROM campaigns WHERE (customer_id=:$customerId) AND (title=:campaignTitle) AND (description=:campaignDescription) AND (start_time=:startTimeStamp) AND (end_time=:endTimeStamp)');

$sqlQuery->bindParam(':customerId', $customerId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sqlQuery->bindParam(':campaignTitle', $campaignTitle);
$sqlQuery->bindParam(':campaignDescription', $campaignDescription);
$sqlQuery->bindParam(':startTimeStamp', $campaignTitle);
$sqlQuery->bindParam(':endTimeStamp', $endTimeStamp);
```

If it doesn't already exist, I want to reuse the PDO statement, changing the SELECT to an INSERT.

The INSERT takes identical parameters. Do I have to bind them again after the second `prepare`?

Comment: You could just use a `replace`.

Comment: Have you tried? What happened? Also your bind parameter should be like this `$sqlQuery->bindParam(':customer', $customerId, PDO::PARAM_INT);` for integers and `$sqlQuery->bindParam(':campaignTitle', $campaignTitle, PDO::PARAM_STR);` for strings and dates.

Comment: In this case, I do not want to update the database. Only if the SELECT fails will I INSERT.

Comment: If you only want to do an insert of the resultset is empty, then you should place your insert statement inside an if-else statement

Comment: I believe the short answer to your question is... Yes, you will have to bind them again. The first instance binds them to a select statement. You place your insert statement inside an if-else statement to be executed **only if** the resultset is empty. You will have to bind them to that insert statement as well.

Comment: There is a myriad of other errors in your code as well. Your sql statement has a misplaced single quote, your sql statement isn't closed properly, a missing open parens in your sql statement, a mis-matched bind, and more. I'm just trying to help, not be critical.

Comment: Ha ha - well spotted. I had just jotted down the code, prior to running, when the question occurred to me. I had not yet debugged the first statement. Thanks for pointing it out (+1)

Comment: I updated the code. If you are **certain** than I need to bind again, please state so as an answer & I will award. But, please, only if you are 100% sure, I am thinking of others who might search & find this question in future. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, if you only tried it yourself, you would find that there is no way to change a query in a statement. So, your assumption will fail even with making a "slight modification" to the query, not even making to the stage of "rebinding" values. There is no "second prepare" either. By calling prepare, you are creating a brand new statement that knows nothing of the others (a behavior is common for any other variable in PHP).